# How is the cure percentage determined?

Tags: two-point-hospital

When a patient is fully diagnosed and about to be cured, a "cure percentage chance" is displayed. This ranges from 20% up to 99%. Assuming the number is accurate, I want to find out how exactly this number is determined. So I'm interested in the formula, not the general description, that part I know of; since here's some factors that have empirically been verified to affect it:

- Inherent disease difficulty. Grout (the easiest disease) always has a 99% rate, while a very hard disease like Touch of Midas can go down to 20 percent.
- Staff skill level in "cure". This is determined by a combination of Seniority (each point giving a 10% skill bonus) and happiness/energy for another 20% boost for a happy, energized doctor or nurse.
- Machines. Level 2 and 3 machines increase the percentage.
- Room objects such as medicine cabinets.
- A cap at 99%.

Exactly how to take the variables and calculate the percentage is unclear to me.

This is valuable information to figure out if I can say give "Stamina Training" to a doctor instead of another level of "Cure" while still reaching 99%, or how many diagnosis levels I can get away with in the DNA room while still curing a reasonable amount of patients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the precise details, I highly recommend the following Steam guide: [Illnesses, diagnosis, tips and more](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1519429114#2940281) under the section "How does treatment work?" I'm sure you'll find the rest of the guide similarly interesting!

In summary, the cure chance is affected by the following:

- Illness difficulty
- Diagnosis certainty
- Machine upgrades, boost objects and staff skill (grouped together)
- Cure cap (usually 99%)

The following formula is given:

> CureChance = DiagnosisCertainty * (((100-IllnessDifficulty) * (1-(StaffSkill/100+Upgrades/100) + CureCap * (StaffSkill/100+Upgrades/100)) /100)

You'll also see a subsection titled "Very Important info for staff training" which answers your other question. Since the treatment cap of a doctor/nurse is 100%, you should consider things like stamina training after levels 4-5, whereas for diagnosis staff, you should keep on training them in diagnosis skills.